# New DbConnection performance

Tags: c#, database, dbconnection

This is my function for selecting data from database:

```
    public DataTable SelectDataTable(string selectStatement, string connectionString)
    {
        using (var oracleConnection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (var command = new OracleCommand(selectStatement, oracleConnection))
            {
                return SelectDataTable(command);
            }
        }
    }
    public DataTable SelectDataTable(OracleCommand command)
    {
        var result = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            var adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(command);
            adapter.Fill(result);
        } catch (OracleException ex)
        {
            throw NewDatabaseException("Error on fill data table.", command.CommandText, ex);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

I call this function very often and I am little afraid that there can be performance issue because I am still creating new DbConnection. Is it better to crete only one DbConnection, store it in field and use it multiplt time?

Comment: According to MSDN *When an OracleConnection object is requested, it is obtained from the pool if a usable connection is available.*

Comment: it's normal to create new connections as and when needed, and to close connections as soon as possible after use. Your code sample complies with this, so no, I wouldn't be worried about performance until you have evidence of a performance problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set MinPoolSize to value greater than 0 in your connection string, so instead of creating new connections, it will be taken from the pool of existing connections. Also set MaxPoolSize at number higher than MinPoolSize.